# Any way to remove all azure scheduled jobs collections without knowing the names of the collections?

Tags: azure

I have looked in depth in to the api documentation both the management library on nuget and the REST docs @http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528946.aspx

I cannot figure out how to list the job collections or to reset the azure schedule system, to default so that the azure management portal can work properly.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528939.aspx not detail how to get the list jobs?  What do you mean by "portal can work properly"?  Is there some other problem you're encountering?

Comment: This is a screen cap from my management portal.. http://d.pr/i/DK9r
I believe it is because i tried to add a job while the portal stuff didnt exist eg. via code.. and now i want to list and delete the job collections or reset the whole thing to clean it up more or less.. so that maybe the portal will work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call Get Cloud Services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495648.aspx)
2. Iterate through the returned list of `<CloudService>` objects
3. For each `<CloudService>` object, call Delete Cloud Service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528936.aspx)

Note that in the future the CloudService logical container will expand beyond just collections of Scheduler objects so if you are building a long term solution you will instead want to iterate through the `<CloudService>` objects and call Delete Job Collection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479787.aspx) instead of just blindly deleting the entire Cloud Service object.

Comment: Also, if you just want to do this quickly and easily (ie. you aren't writing an automated tool) then you can use the Service Management REST API functionality of AzureTools (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx).  It shouldn't take more than ~5 minutes to iterate through and delete everything using that tool.

Comment: Thanks you guys this looks to be the answer.. Working at cleaning it up

Comment: K this partially solved my issue it killed the jobs running but my portal is still busted. Diggin more.. Thanks again.